# How to provide reference of page in Tab of TabBar in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I created xamarin forms project of a shell template. Now I need to add the reference to my page. Like

```
<TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Shop" Icon="shop.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ExplorePage}"/>
        </Tab>        
</TabBar>
```

I created my page in child folder of views

[image]

I need to give the reference in ContentTemplate. How can I give it?

Comment: Add its namespace (like you added the `views` namespace), and then `{DataTemplate nmspc:DashBoard}`. This should work.

Comment: got in reference i added like xmlns:Dashboard="clr-namespace:UI.Mobile.Views.Dashboard" in code  <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Dashboard:Dashboard}" />....Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference `xmlns:Dashboard="clr-namespace:UI.Mobile.Views.Dashboard"` after the by using reference tag name we can use like  `<ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Dashboard:PartnerDashboard}" />`